# thread is not started

Tags: c#, winforms, multithreading

This must be a really dumb question. I'm trying to run a time consuming process in a new thread so I'll be able to show progress bar. I've never used threading before. I must do something wrong because when I'm using the `.Start()` method nothing seems to happen.

```
private void btnStart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    clsScrap oScrap = new clsScrap(txtInputFilename.Text,txtImgSrc.Text);
    Thread ScrapThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(oScrap.Scrap));
    ScrapThread.Start();
    while (oScrap.GetLinkCount() < 0) ;
    myProgressBar.Minimum = 1;
    myProgressBar.Maximum = oScrap.GetLinkCount();

    while (ScrapThread.IsAlive)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000 * 30);
        myProgressBar.Value = oScrap.GetCurrLinkNo();
    }
}
```

I put a breakpoint at the begining of oScrap.Scrap() but it never gets there. After the `ScrapThread.Start();` line it just moves to the next while loop and gets stuck there (The function `oScrap.GetLinkCount()` suppose to return positive value quickly after initializing)

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 5):

You are sleeping on the UI thread (your button click event runs on the UI thread). Because your UI thread doesn't get a chance to update the Window (you only sleep or set a value), you don't see any change.

Try using a `BackgroundWorker` instead.
It provides events that you can process when the Progress has changed.  You can subscribe to the Events [`ProgressChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.progresschanged.aspx) and [`RunWorkerCompleted`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.runworkercompleted.aspx) to get notified of what's happening, and from your BackgroundWorker method, you can [`ReportProgress`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka89zff4.aspx) to trigger the `ProgressChanged` event.

See here for more information and an example:

[MSDN Documentation for BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx)

Comment: thank you for your answer. yes, i thought about using the backgroundworker, but I need to execute one very long procedure (the oScrap.Scrap() can take hours) and until it is not finished I can not change the progress of the background worker. What I don't understand is why ScrapThread.Start(); does not invoke the oScrap.Scrap() method. not only the progress bar is not changed but the oScrap.Scrap() does not produce no result. Sorry for complicating simple things I'm newbie on this. thanks a lot for the help, really appreciated.

Comment: The progress bar is not changed because the UI thread doesn't get a chance to repaint the ProgressBar. If it's a really long process, display some UI to notify the user of that. The progress of the Background worker would be exactly the value that you set to your progressbar.